# How can I filter marketing campaigns out of my decomposed seasonal data?

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, seasonality, trend

I've recently jumped into the deep end of statistical analysis of revenue. I've learned a ton about statistics, probability, decomposition (stl), and the Python and R languages. I feel like I'm climbing the learning curve well, even though it's a steep one. Many of my largest hurdles are simply discovering the correct terms to search for on Google in this new field to me.

TL;DR: **What search terms, statistical concepts, or R packages would you use to find the best method of filtering revenue caused by marketing campaigns out of the baseline seasonality of a business?**

The end goal that I have now is to filter out marketing effects on historical data to gain a base and to then run some predictive analysis on  our gross revenue prior to future marketing efforts.

I currently have about 4 years of monthly sales revenue and have been able to successfully decompose it with the stl() function in R, do some prediction with various methods including Holt-Winters.

My problem is that I believe some aggressive marketing campaigns in our past is severely corrupting my seasonal vector (and therefore my predictions).

In addition to the 4 years of sales data I have 4 years of monthly data about our email campaigns and have been able to determine a strong correlation between emails sent per month and gross revenue (.74) I was hoping that I might be able to use that data to filter out the marketing effects on gross_revenue and find a better representation of our seasonal trends without marketing effects.

I've looked a little into Marketing Mix Modeling but I wasn't convinced that was the correct tree to bark up and if i could correlate it with my predictive efforts anyway.

I know that pictures and data often speak better than i do, so here's some data I've generated to better communicate my current problem. In both cases I feel like the spikes where we pushed marketing in the top bars have too much influence on the seasonality in the 3rd bars.

Spikes show marketing efforts and are distorting seasonality

[image: Decomposition of time series]

Code for above plot:

```
ds2 <- ts(ds$gross, start=c(2011,7), frequency=12)
fit <- decompose(ds2, type="multiplicative")
plot(fit)
```

This one is decomposed with stl()
[image: Decomposed with stl()]

Code used to generate above plot

```
ds2 <- ts(ds$gross, start=c(2011,7), frequency=12)
fit <- decompose(ds2, type="multiplicative")
plot(fit)
```

Comment: If you know the amount of adstock purchased you can start to back into an impact factor for your model. Some MMM models in Statsmodels if it's any help - http://www.andrewwalterowens.com/post/111019666926/marketing-mix-modeling-using-statsmodels-part-1